# Symbol lookup error when pressing button on raspberry pi breadboard

Tags: node.js, breadboard

I have a raspberry with a breadboard and a button connected to the breadboard. I am running this simple Node.js program on Raspbian:

```
var GPIO = require('onoff').Gpio,
    button = new GPIO(17, 'in', 'both');

button.watch(function(err, value){
    console.log('button pressed');
});
```

I also used:

```
gpio-admin export 17
gpio-admin export 18
gpio-admin export 21
```

Whenever I pressed the button, it would `console.log` and the program worked perfectly. The problem is that I didn't use it for a few days and next time I turn the raspberry pi on, the same program would throw this error whenever you press the button:

```
node: symbol lookup error: /home/pi/learn/new/node_modules/onoff/node_modules/epoll/build/Release/epoll.node: undefined symbol: _ZN4node12MakeCallbackEN2v86HandleINS0_6ObjectEEENS1_INS0_8FunctionEEEiPNS1_INS0_5ValueEEE
```

I have tried reinstalling the `'onoff'` dependency, I have tried running the same program, still no success.

I need to mention that the hardware has not been touched since it worked last time. If I am trying to light an LED, it's fine. It's only the button that throws the error.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I am seeing this too. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, I still haven't figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. You may have to upgrade nodejs and npm. Once done, reinstall onoff.

Hope it helps. Here is the link to my resolution in github :

https://github.com/fivdi/onoff/issues/42